# Is there a way to use a Canon 60d as general SD card reader?

Tags: canon-60d, sdcard, usb

My computer doesn't have an sd card reader, but one of my cameras records more information than just RAW or JPG. That camera doesn't have a cable for it readily available.

I was wondering if there is a way that I can put the SD card in my Canon 60d, connect that to  my computer, and have it show me all the files, instead of just RAW + JPG files?

I'm currently using Microsoft Windows.

Comment: edit: got its proprietary cable. But this situation could be similar to others

Comment: Really? Considering SD cards readers can be had for under $7, I wouldn't even bother trying. Card readers are self powered (do not run down the camera batter) and faster than the camera at transferring.

Comment: and the fact that the camera is only displaying .jpg and raw files when connected via usb is clearly a software limitation only, seems like "there should be an app for that"

Comment: On some cameras (not sure about the 60D) there is an option to connect USB using MSD or PTP protocol. What you are seeing is the latter. What you want is the former. Check if there is an option for that in your setup menu.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest biting the bullet and getting a dedicated card reader. You can get a good one under $20, possibly under $10, they are faster at file transfers than a camera, and they are small and will easily fit in a camera bag.

Answer (score 0):

Following @cadmium's direction, you can spend a bit more and get a new MacBook Pro, which has a SD card built in. I am sure that other brands of modern laptops have SD card ports.

Comment: 'a bit more'...

Comment: reminds me on the facebook group 'I need a new flat, there is a spider in the old one.'

Comment: I'm a huge fan of the MacBook Pro, including the 2012 model in early 2016, but telling a Windows user to buy a new Mac so that they can read SD cards is ridiculous.

Comment: Caleb, can you please take a second and look at the date of my comment.

My MacBook Pro cost a bit more than $3000, which is only a little bit more than @cadmium's suggested $20